# SQL foreign key to multiple tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, foreign-keys, relational-database, data-modeling

I am creating a health and safety app for 30 different forms; each form has about 50 questions which are pass or fail questions, and they want to be able to take a few pictures as evidence for each question. If the answer to a question is fail, they need to create an action to fix the issue. The forms are entirely different from each other below are some examples.

- Plant and equipment inspection
- Fire safety inspection
- Site weekly inspection
- Working at hight inspection

Furthermore, each form needs to be linked to a project.

So far, I have created a Project table, a Site_Weekly_Inspection table (one of the forms) with a foreign key to the project, an Action table with a foreign key site_weekly_inspection and an image table with a foreign key to site_weekly_inspection.

Additionally, in the action and image table, I used action_category and image_category to be able to link the images and actions to the individual questions.

[My database so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0mbBF.png)

I don't want to create a separate image and action table for each form. What would be the MOST CORRECT way of making this database?

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: There isn't much detail to go on here. All we have is a vague explanation of what you are trying to do and a partial look at what you have tried so far.

Comment: Why does every form need its own table? Only if the data in each is very different then you would need that. And then you can use a polymorphic association, with a "supertable" of all forms, plus one table per form, and with the same primary key as the supertable and foreign-keyed to it in  a 1:1 relationship

Comment: Thank you for your reply @Charlieface . Each form has about 50 questions which are pass or fail questions and they want to be able to take a few pictures as evidence. If the answer to a question is fail they need to create an action to fix the issue. The forms are entirely different from each other.

Comment: Please clarify via edits, not comments.  Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Paraphrase or quote from other text. Give just what you need & relate it to your problem. Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image. [ask] [Help] Please ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question re where & how you are 1st stuck in what published presentation of what information modelling & DB design method.

Comment: Are they entirely different in the sense that they cannot be represented in the same structure, the same columns? Can you not have a table `Form (FormId, QuestionId, Answer)` or something like that, plus another table `Evidence (QuestionId, Image)` and another `Action (QuestionId, Action)`?

Answer (score 0):

You will need table(s) in the middle.

1. Inspection_Action table - lists all possible actions
   Inspection_Action_id
2. Inspection_Image table (or just Image )- lists all images
   Inspection_Image_id (PK)
3. Site_Weekly_Inspection_Action
   Site_Weekly_Inspection_Action_id
   Inspection_Action_id (FK points to Inspection_Action)
4. If only one image per site / weekly add to Site_Weekly_Inspection table
   Inspection_Image_id (FK points to Inspection_Image)
5. If more than one image per site /weekly add table Site_Weekly_Inspection_Images
   Site_Weekly_Inspection_Image_id (PK)
   Inspection_Image_id (FK points to Inspection_Image)

You will need to figure out how to share images and actions in UI